# SQL Perfomance : Subselects in joins or direct joins?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, join

I have got a question on the performance of the below tables\

Table A -- Has only 5 customer ID's(5 Rows 1 column)
Table B -- Is the master base for all Customer's and their information.(1 Million Rows and 500 Columns)

Query 1:-

```
Select A.*,
       B.Age
from A
left join B
on A.Customer_id = B.Customer_id;
```

Query 2:-

```
Select a.*,
       B.Age
from A
left join
(select Customer_id,age from B) C
on A.Customer_id = C.Customer_id;
```

The main question of performance here is because of the presence of 500 columns in Table B. 
I feel the 2nd Query is better as SQL wont have to create a temporary table during the join containing all columns from table B.

Please let me know if this is wrong?

Comment: using indexes on required column make query run  faster

Comment: The execution plans will tell you which one is better.

Comment: How do i check out the execution plan for this ?

Answer (score 1):

> I feel the 2nd Query is better as SQL wont have to create a temporary table during the join containing all columns from table B.

You can tell whether Oracle does create a temporary table during the execution or not from the explain plan. You should also consider whether the Oracle kernel developers would not have got round such an obvious performance problem if it existed.

As it happens, there will be no temporary table, and there is nothing wrong with your first query. There is almost never a need to manipulate the query for performance reasons -- write queries that are the best encapsulation of the logic you require.

Comment: Can you tell which query is faster and why (choose one between the 2 shown above) ?

Comment: They probably perform exactly the same, because the query optimiser will transform the second query into the first query via a mechanism called view merging.

Comment: can you give me some links to read about the query optimiser and view merging?

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/optimizer_transformations_view_merging_part_1 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_b (customer_id)
```

then use

```
Select a.*,
       B.Age 
from A 
left join (select Customer_id,
                  age 
           from B) C 
        on A.Customer_id = C.Customer_id;
```

Comment: Why the inline view for selecting from B?

Comment: that is to simplify complex queries by removing join operations and condensing several separate queries into a single query ?

Comment: I don't see a benefit over just joining to "B", in this case though

Answer (score 0):

500 columns is rather extensive.

Maybe you can create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
          ON table_b (customer_id, 
                      age
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

sub query in select is faster than using join *(no matter if direct join or sub select)*

```
select 
   a.*,
   (select b.age 
    from b
    where b.customer_id = a.customer_id)
from a
```

note:

- it behaves like outer join (return empty field in age if customer_id from b doesn't exists in a)
- the sub query should return only one row from b per row from a.

Comment: I'd like to see some supporting evidence for the assertion that "sub query in select is faster than using join". In the past it has generally meant excluding certain join methods, and can lead to performance problems. I don't believe that it is true, I'm afraid.